# Clojure macro for creating a map

Tags: dictionary, macros, clojure

I have a macro for creating a hash-map. I should send a name of a mashup and contents that get from calling a function (in this example it is a function xx).

```
(defmacro data-for-mashup [mashup-name func]  
`(map  {} {:title :content} {~mashup-name (~@func)}))
```

The macro should get any mashup name and any function, that's why I wanted it to be a macro.

Wnen I call it  I want the result to look like this

```
{:title "Events Mashup"
 :content [{ :event-name "event name 1"
                    :performer "performer 1"
                  :date "date 1"
                       :start-time "start time 1"
                       :end-time "end time 1"}
  {:event-name "event name 2"
                       :performer "performer 2"
                      :date "date 2"
                       :start-time "start time 2"
                       :end-time "end time 2"}]}
```

The value of content tag is in fact a vector of maps.

A call to a macro should get the result like this

```
(data-for-mashup "events" (xx))
```

in REPL I get this as a result

```
(["events" #<datamodel$xx mashup_dsl.datamodel$xx@530f0fbd>])
```

macroexpand-1 results in this

```
(macroexpand-1 `(data-for-mashup "events" (xx)))  
(clojure.core/map {} {:title :content} {"events" mashup-dsl.datamodel/xx})
```

(The xx is a function in my namespace.)

When in fact I want it to expand to this

```
(map {} {:title :content} {"events" (xx)})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will get better answers if you specify what your output should look like. Also, there is nothing here that indicates this should have to be a macro, and though I have no idea what you are trying to do, it will likely be easier using a function rather than a macro.

Comment: @noisesmith I added the brief explanation of what I intend to do. I want to make a macro because I want to be able to call it with any function (xx) in this example. Maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: Any function can take any other function as an argument. Why do you need the function to be inside parenthesis? Where does the :content keyword end up? Where does the :event-data keyword come from?

Comment: @noisesmith yes I see it now, when I checked your answer, I also edited my question and changed that :event-data tag is in fact :content tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, are you trying to create a call to map, or a hash-map?

map is for applying its first arg to each element of the other args. Applying {} to something will not make a hash-map. An empty hashmap will return nil for any single argument.

```
user> (map {} [:a :b :c])
(nil nil nil)
```

Two arguments provided to an empty hashmap as a function, will always return the second argument. What are you trying to do here?

```
user> ({} :a 0)
0

user> (map {} [:args :here :are-meaningless] (range))
(0 1 2)
```

Next, ~@ takes the top level of nesting off of the argument. If you want to return the function inside a list, you need to construct a list around it. quote (also written as ') will prevent a pair of parens from causing application of a function, and instead construct a list.

```
user> (macroexpand-1 ''(+))
(quote (+))

user> (quote (+))
(+)

user> (defmacro data-for-mashup [mashup-name func]  
        `(map  {} {:title :content} {~mashup-name '(~@func)}))
#'user/data-for-mashup
user> (macroexpand-1 '(data-for-mashup "events" (+)))
(clojure.core/map {} {:title :content} {"events" (quote (+))})
user> (data-for-mashup "events" (+))
(["events" (+)])
```

This is identical to not using ~@, and just using ~ directly, but quoting what it returns.

```
user> (defmacro data-for-mashup [mashup-name func]  
        `(map  {} {:title :content} {~mashup-name '~func}))
#'user/data-for-mashup
user> (macroexpand-1 '(data-for-mashup "events" (+)))
(clojure.core/map {} {:title :content} {"events" (quote (+))})
user> (data-for-mashup "events" (+))
(["events" (+)])
```

If you are trying to construct a hash-map, I think one of the following definitions is likely what you want:

```
user> (defmacro data-for-mashup [mashup-name func]  
        `(zipmap [:title :content] [~mashup-name '~func]))
#'user/data-for-mashup
user> (data-for-mashup "events" (+))
{:content (+), :title "events"}

user> (defn data-for-mashup [mashup-name val] (zipmap [:title :content] [mashup-name val]))
#'user/data-for-mashup
user> (data-for-mashup "events" (+))
{:content 0, :title "events"}
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to construct a hash-map, but I want to be able to send the function xx which creates a map of maps, that in fact represents the contents of a mashup. This other solution of yours works just fine, with one problem, since my contents come from calling a function, the val of :content tag is a list, and I want it to be a vector.

Comment: I've just changed your answer and added (vec val) instead of just val. I know that you'd do it yourself if I have put the expected result in the first place. Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: The zipmap is really not necessary. If you insist on passing a function and that the function will be called inside the macro, don't pass it in brackets but simply the function symbol. Use this macro (defmacro data-for-mashup
 [mashup-name content-fn]
 `{:title ~mashup-name
     :content (vec (~content-fn))}). If you are fine with just passing the list and having it converted to a vector use (defmacro data-for-mashup
 [mashup-name content]
 `{:title ~mashup-name
     :content (vec ~content)}).

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question right, you can use a function here, instead of a macro. I'd strongly recommend using functions whenever you can. They are much more composable and easier to read.

```
;; This mashup function is a higher-order function
;; It takes *another* function as an argument (f here is your content-getting function)
(defn data-for-mashup [mashup-name f]  
    {:title mashup-name :content (f)})

;; A sample content getting function
(defn events-content []
  [{:event-name "Great concert"}
   {:event-name "Above Average concert"}])

;; Call the data-for-mashup with the title and the content-getting function
(data-for-mashup "events" events-content)

;; Result
{:title "events"
 :content
    [{:event-name "Great concert"}
     {:event-name "Above Average concert"}]}
```